# ##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted

Tags: azure-pipelines

If I run my Azure DevOps pipeline I am getting the below-mentioned error. If anyone knows about this issue please help me.

> [error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form
> https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request

[image]

Comment: Worth looking at this: https://www.compilemode.com/2021/04/no-hosted-parallelism-has-been-purchased-or-granted-azure-devops.html looks like it's recently changed

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/ or https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/ for a bit more information

Comment: And how about creating a self hosted agent rather than waiting for Microsofts approval. Check out my video and especially check out Chapter 14 which shows how Selfhosted agents can be created https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aonA7Kb7WGE

Answer (score 30):

Microsoft has temporarily disabled the free grant of parallel jobs for public projects and for certain private projects in new organizations. However, you can request this grant by submitting a request. Existing organizations and projects are not affected. Please note that it takes us 2-3 business days to respond to your free tier requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted

Comment: I know this is the most voted answer but one thing you can also do is create a self hosted agent. In other words make your local computer as an agent and register it on Azure Devops. You can go through by Azure devops step by step video  and watch Chapter 14 where i shown how to create Self hosted agents https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aonA7Kb7WGE 

Its just a simple power shell script which we need to run.

Comment: @ShivprasadKoirala - That solution sucks. I know I can build this on my own machine, I've been doing it for years. I want a DevOps that doesn't depend on one of my machines being up and running.

Comment: Great! No problem! I don't mind paying. How do I purchase the service?

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft has changed the policy to allow the free tier of a hosted agent pools for public and private projects of newly created DevOps organizations by citing the reason that many are abusing this feature by sending a huge amount of traffic on these hosted agents pools. Due to this reason, many are getting the following error during the build pipeline.

Try this solution:

https://www.compilemode.com/2021/04/no-hosted-parallelism-has-been-purchased-or-granted-azure-devops.html

Answer (score 7):

To get free tier access you can submit request on below Microsoft portal. Generally, it takes 2-3 business days.

https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request

Comment: I don't need the charity, just tell me how I can pay for the service.

Comment: @QuarkSoup - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/contact/

Comment: @QuarkSoup Did someone break your web search finger? Look it up yourself since you don't need charity.